# MySqlAdapter throwing a Fatal Exception when migrating to a newer version of the connector

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

To give you a bit of context, I have a web application in asp.net working just fine with the MySql Connector 5.0.9 Today I was asked to do some prototyping on using the MySQL membership I had to update the driver to 6.0.7 and now my previous code isn't working anymore and it is trowing an exception with this message.

Fatal error encountered during command execution.

The code:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT  currentt.id, currentt.firstname, currentt.lastname,currentt.iscommented,currentt.rowversion,ifnull(parent.id,0) as parentid, parent.rowversion as parentversion,child.id as childid,child.rowversion as childversion FROM    (SELECT  hierarchy(id) AS id, @level AS level FROM    (SELECT  @start_with := 0, @id := @start_with,@level := 0) vars, names2 WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL) ho JOIN    names2 currentt ON currentt.id = ho.id left outer join names2 as parent on (currentt.parent=parent.id) left outer join names2 as child on (child.parent = currentt.id and child.id<>currentt.id)order by level",connection);

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            ds = new StrongDataSet();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "names");//exception thrown here
            connection.Close();
```

After doing some research I assume that my problem is coming from the nested select statement where I set some variable to use a stored procedure @start_time,@level & @id

Now I am confused this seems to be an error prevention failure since it is the parameterized query notation but I am not sure how to modify my code to be compliant with the new MySQL driver ?

Any suggestions ...
re!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a known problem with @sql variables and Connector variables.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-connection-options.html

Try set `Allow User Variables=true`  in your connection string. otherwise, try MySQLScript.

Comment: This is totally a right answer thanks. I bookmarked the connector option page for future use! my connection string now looks like the following: `private const string ConnStr = "Server=localhost;Database=test;uid=root;pwd=password;Allow User Variables=true";`

Comment: I learned this page many times, as there are many useful options.